# Display Content based On Option Clicked in A Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I spent several hours on this and couldn't find a solution that worked, so I'm turning to you :) As you can see from this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/PPcgE/), I was able to target the radio buttons by click with this code:

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function (e) {
    if ($('.cos-cond').is(":visible")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
        var cls = [$('.one'), $('.two'), $('.three'), $('.four'), $('.five'), $('.six'), $('.seven'), $('.eight'), $('.nine'), $('.ten')];
        for (i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
            if (cls[i].attr('title') === clicked) {
                cls[i].fadeIn('fast', function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('.cos-cond').fadeOut('slow');}, 5000);
                });
            } 
        }
    }
});
```

I'm trying to do exactly the same thing (displaying either `span.eleven`, `span.twelve` or `span.thirteen` this time) based on which `option` is clicked/selected in the `select` box. The best I've been able to manage is to get all three to appear at once.

Comment: Do you have the code that applies to the select? I looked at the fiddle and all it shows is this same code here. You need to post the working code for the select if you hope to get an answer.

Comment: also, the code in the fiddle doesn't work either.  No matter which cosmetic condition number i select it shows the same message below it.

Comment: this fixes your original code, so radio  button messages work: http://jsfiddle.net/PPcgE/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shouldn't be longer than this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function (e) {
        $('.cos-cond, .work-cond').hide();
        var clicked = $(this).attr('title');
        $('span.cos-cond[title=' + clicked + ']').fadeIn(300);
    });
    $("select").change(function (e) {
        $('.cos-cond, .work-cond').hide();
        var value = $(this).val();
        var title = $('option[value="' + value + '"]', this).attr('title');
        $('span.work-cond.' + title).fadeIn(300);
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PPcgE/5/

Comment: Thank you! I was definitely over-thinking it. A quick question: what exactly is the `e` parameter of the function accomplishing? It looks like maybe it works the same way the `.each()` method works?

Comment: e is the javascript event object (Try console.log(e.type, e.screenX) to dump event properties) but the .each method arguments are the object index in the collection and the object itself.

Comment: I'm having this same discussion with another user below. The code works the same with or without the event object, so I guess I'm just curious why one would or wouldn't use it.

Comment: This is definitely the sleeker option. My only question is why you included `this` in the jQuery object. Again, the code works exactly the same with or without it. Oh, also, I've not yet seen the `' + var + '` syntax. Is that just the standard syntax for the addition of a single variable in place of an HTML attribute?

Comment: It can be omitted if you won't use it but it is useful for example to retrieve mouse pointer coordinates, to prevent default event behaviour (like you did in your example (e.preventDefault())

Comment: this in this example referers to the select DOM. This code $('option[value="' + value + '"]', this) looks for options only within the "this" select DOM. In your example, it gives the same result because in your HTML code you have only "one" select, and with more than one select, the result can be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is broken, [i've create a fiddle that fixes it.](http://jsfiddle.net/PPcgE/4/)

Your problem was when you were fading out, your selector was selecting all of them, visible or not, and then showing ALL of them while fading out.. thus always showing the last one (topmost).

```
if (cls[i].attr('title') === clicked) {
    cls[i].fadeIn('fast', function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.cos-cond:visible').fadeOut('slow');}, 5000);
    });
}
```

Beyond that you need to provide your attempt at how you tried to get the dropdown box working.  You only provided the old code and nothing more.

Comment: @erikunia: I appreciate the feedback. I'm not sure what the problem was for you. That code (while not ideal) was working fine for me and for others in the fiddle I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".emf-hide").change(function(e){
        var val = $(".emf-hide option:selected").val();
        $('.work-cond').hide();
        switch(val){
        case 'Like New - No Functional Problems':
              $('.eleven').show();    
         break;       
         case 'Minor Functional Problems':
              $('.twelve').show();    
         break;       
         case 'Non-functional':
              $('.thirteen').show();    
         break;       
        }
    });
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PPcgE/1/)

Comment: Much obliged! I was trying to target them by click which just didn't work. I was unaware of the `.change()` method. A quick question: Does adding the `e` parameter to the function make sure the events change each time instead of piling up?

Comment: the e parameter captures the event. but i didnt understand `make sure the events change each time instead of piling up?`

Comment: One of the problems I was having in my early attempts was that the click would show the proper content, but not disappear it on a new click, and the `span`s were just piling up on top of each other. Your code seems to work the same with or without the `e` parameter, so I was just curious why it was there.

Comment: I ended up going with the suggestion below, but as a beginner it's very helpful for me to see the myriad possible solutions to a problem. I now know what the `.change` method is, and that it can be used with or without a `switch` statement. I very much appreciate the input.